# Group of vs. Group in

Tags: prepositions, difference

They sound the same to me. Are they interchangeable?

I hear people say "in a group," but when I use it in my writing, the auto-correct changed it to "of a group." I checked the grammar book and think they are both grammatical, so I'm wondering if there is a difference between these two.

For example:

> Please notify the members **in** your group **or** the members **of** your group

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in meaning but in most cases it is a very subtle one. **In** denotes that you/they/that is "part of something", whilst **of** denotes "belonging to something"

---

**in** preposition (**PART**): forming a part of something:

He used to be the lead singer **in** a rock band.

CED [In](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in)

---

**of** preposition (**POSSESSION**); used to show possession, belonging, or origin:

employees **of** the company

CED [Of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)

---

Please notify the members in your group = Please notify the members who are **part of your** group

Therefore this does not necessarily include all members

or

Please notify the members of your group = Please notify the members **who belong** to your group

Whilst this would inherently include all members

Comment: Common use is belong to a or "of" a group; Example "Quickly list all groups a user is member of or owner of in Office 365"

Answer (score 1):

"members of a group" is more idiomatic for referring to a group of people as a whole.  Other similar expressions include "employees of a company," "members of Congress," or "citizens of a country."

"members in a group" would be more commonly used in cases like "there should be 3 members in a group."

Answer (score 0):

For me personally, in this situation *members **of** a group* feels more like something people have been assigned to, something they belong to - a status you're talking about in a more general sense.

*Members **in** a group* carries more of an immediate, dynamic feel - like the group is actually doing something together, actively working on something, or several people have physically formed a group by coming together. It feels more like you're describing a specific situation, rather than a category people have been assigned to, if that makes sense.

It's really a (subjective) tonal nuance - *of* and *in* both carry the same idea in this context, and are interchangeable outside of a few common phrasings (e.g. several people together are *in a group*, *of a group* works but probably sounds unusual to most people).

---

*In* is also a preposition for actual physical location, so in some contexts (where an organisation is also a place) it might be unclear which meaning you're going for:

- *There are 50 members of this gym* - 50 people have joined this gym
- *There are 50 members in this gym* - 50 of the people who have joined (there may be more!) are inside this gym right now

I think that's partly why *in* feels more immediate in general, it carries that same sense of "the situation right here, right now", whereas *of* can sound more distant and abstract.